# Does editing an object within a function mean I need to return it back to update the value

Tags: java

If I edit the data of an object in a function do I need to return the object back to update it in java.

Say I have something like this:

```java
  public void foo1() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    someFunction(foo);
    // Is the state of foo changed here or not?
  }

  public void someFunction(Foo foo) {
    foo.doSomething();
  }
```

I know objects are passed by reference in java. Will this mean the object is updated/changed at the end of the foo1() function or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `foo` change? It's *possible* but it depends on what the method does.

Here's an example where `foo` does not change:

```
public class NoChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.noChange();
    }
}

class Foo {
    private int n = 0;
    public void noChange() {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

If you run this code, the call to `foo.noChange()` will print out "0", and nothing in `foo` will change.

Here's a slight modification of that example which introduces a `doChange()` method on class `Foo`. The new method *does* change something in an instance of `Foo` – specifically, it takes the value of `n` and increments it by one.

```
public class YesChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.doChange(); // increment n by one
        foo.noChange(); // print out n
    }
}

class Foo {
    private int n = 0;

    public void noChange() {
        System.out.println(n);
    }

    public void doChange() {
        n++;
    }
}
```

When you run that second example code – which first calls `doChange()`, then calls `noChange()` to print out current "n" – the output is "1".

So, the behavior depends on whether the method changes state (for example, by changing setting a value such as incrementing a number) or has side effects (the method might call some other method which in turn does change state). If the method does none of these things, it would be a ["pure function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).